# Unable to find CUDA in user preferences for version 2.79

Tags: customization, gpu

I'm trying to find CUDA for GPU rendering in the user preferences and all it shows is this:

[image]

How can I fix this?  My computer is a Lenovo Y50 and the GPU is Nvidia GeForce GTX 860M.  Is my GPU no longer supported or is there another reason?

Thanks

Comment: update the drivers for the GPU

Comment: I tried that and also restarted my computer.  Still doesn't show.

Comment: What os are you using?

Comment: I'm using windows 10

Comment: I figured it out.  Turns out I had downloaded a faulty version of Blender 2.79 Fracture Modifier Build (which I always use).  If you do get the the Fracture Modifier build (have to use it as a build; there is no addon), make sure you get the latest version.  I got mine from Dennis Fassbaender's site.